# Replace the string in Single shot using perl

Tags: regex, perl

My input:

```
my $tmp = "rrccllrrc";
```

Expected Output:

```
$tmp = "right right center center left left right right center"; #End should not be spaced definitely.
```

My Code:

```
$tmp=~s/c/center /g;
$tmp=~s/l/left /g;
$tmp=~s/r/right /g;
```

Someone can help to shorten the way to replace the regex as much possible.

Comment: Add this after your code : `$tmp =~ s/\s*$//g;`

Comment: @AbhiNickz: will do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can do without a regex as well

```
my %repl = (c => 'center', l => 'left', r => 'right');

$tmp = join ' ', map { $repl{$_} }  split '', $tmp;
```

The [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) with the pattern `''` breaks a string into a list of its characters, and [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) uses the hash to replace each by its full word. The output list of `map` is joined by space.

---

*Updated to comments*

If the original string contains yet other characters, can filter them out first

```
$tmp = join ' ', map { $repl{$_} } grep { /c|l|r/ } split '', $tmp;
```

or, use an empty list in the `map` for anything that isn't defined in the hash

```
$tmp = join ' ', map { $repl{$_} // () } split '', $tmp;
```

This removes altogether everything other than `c|l|r`. To keep them in the result

```
$tmp = join ' ', map { $repl{$_} // $_ } split '', $tmp;
```

which has them separated by space as well.  To keep them *together* need to tweak it further.

Comment: I'd suggest that a hash written with `=>` would be a clearer way of showing what's happening here.

Comment: @zdim: `Use of uninitialized value in join or string at a.pl line ` I am getting this error.

Comment: @ssr1012  What strings are you feeding to this? Whatever chars are in the string they have to be in the hash.  If the string can have yet other ones, which you'd discard, this is easily adjusted, for example by adding `grep { /c|l|r/ }` after `split` (this would remove others altogether). Let me know.

Comment: @Sobrique Indeed. It was typed quickly and felt easy to read, but there is no reason for the shortcut.  Thank you.

Comment: You could build the `grep` operation into the `map` if you just did a  `map { $repl{$_} // () }` - so it'll return the looked up element or an empty list if there isn't one. (Or have it return a 'default' if you prefer)

Answer (score 6):

You can use a hash of replacements in the substitution:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $tmp = "rrccllrrc";

my %replace = ( r => 'right',
                c => 'center',
                l => 'left' );

$tmp =~ s/(.)/$replace{$1} /g;
chop $tmp;
say "<$tmp>";
```